# Having problems using KendoUI grid with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular-kendo

I'm evaluating KendoUI for use within my Angular applications.
I'm having issues with using KendoUI Gird widget: I specify the data source to be a JSON array defined in my controller, but I got absolutely nothing on the page, not even an empty grid.

Here is my html:

```
<div>

<kendo-grid k-data-source="dataSource">

</kendo-grid>

</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('wizardApp').controller('ApplicationGeneralWizardCtrl', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
            console.log('Entering ApplicationGeneralWizardCtrl');
         $scope.dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: [
                { id: 1, name: 'Tennis Balls', department: 'Sports', lastShipment: '10/01/2013' },
                { id: 2, name: 'Basket Balls', department: 'Sports', lastShipment: '10/02/2013' },
                { id: 3, name: 'Oil', department: 'Auto', lastShipment: '10/01/2013' },
                { id: 4, name: 'Filters', department: 'Auto', lastShipment: '10/01/2013' },
                { id: 5, name: 'Dresser', department: 'Home Furnishings', lastShipment: '10/01/2013' }

            ],
             columns:
                 [
                     { "field": "name", "title": "Name"},
                     { "field": "department", "title": "Department"},
                     { "field": "lastShipment", "title": "Last Shipment" }
                 ]
         });

    }
]);
```

Here is my main app.js:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('wizardApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute',
  'mgo-angular-wizard',
    'ngGrid',
    'kendo.directives'
]);

app.value('host', false /*use local host*/ ? "http://localhost:63428" : "http://sampleservice.breezejs.com");

app.controller('ApplicationTableCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope','ngGrid',
    function ($scope, $location, $rootScope) {

    }
]);

app.controller('MainCtrl',
    ['$scope',  'datacontext','$timeout','WizardHandler','$location',
        function($scope, datacontext, $timeout,WizardHandler,$location) {

            function Customer(name,number,address,contact)
            {
                this.customerName = name;
                this.customerNumber = number;
                this.customerAddress = address;
                this.customerContact = contact;
            }

            console.log('created MainCtrl');
            $scope.items = [];
//            $scope.logList = logger.logList;
//            $scope.lastLog = function(){return logger.lastLog;};

            $scope.step_1_Action = function(name,number){
                 console.log('MainCtrl : step_1_Action dataInput:  ' + name + '  ' + number);

                $scope.currentCustomer = new Customer('','','','');
                 $scope.currentCustomer.customerName = name;
                 $scope.currentCustomer.customerNumber = number;
                    }
            $scope.step_2_Action = function(address,contact){
                console.log('MainCtrl : step_2_Action dataInput:  ' + address + '   ' + contact);
                $scope.currentCustomer.customerAddress = address;
                $scope.currentCustomer.customerContact = contact;
                    }
            $scope.saveCustomerRecord = function(){
                 datacontext.addCustomer($scope.currentCustomer);
                 datacontext.commit();
                $scope.currentCustomer = new Customer('','','','');
                 //$scope.step1Form.$setPristine();
                 $scope.currentCustomer = {};
                 WizardHandler.wizard().goTo(0);
            }


        }]

);

app
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
        .when('/IntroductionWizard', {
            templateUrl: 'views/Wizards/IntroductionWizard/IntroductionWizard.html',
            controller: 'IntroductionWizardCtrl'
        })
        .when('/ApplicationGeneralWizard', {
            templateUrl: 'views/Wizards/ApplicationGeneralWizard/ApplicationGeneralWizard.html',
            controller: 'ApplicationGeneralWizardCtrl'
        })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }).run(
    function ($rootScope, $location) {
        $rootScope.go = function (path) {
            $location.path(path);
        }
    });
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">



    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-kendo.js"></script>

    <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body ng-app="wizardApp">

    <div class="container" ng-view=""></div>
    <script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>




    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>


    <!-- Breeze: -->
    <script src="scripts/q.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/breeze.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/breeze.angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/breeze.metadata-helper.js"></script>

    <!-- ng-grid: -->

    <script src="bower_components/ng-grid/build/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/ng-grid/ng-grid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />

    <!-- the actual app: -->

        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/model.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/datacontext.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/metadataFactory.js"></script>



        <script src="scripts/controllers/introductionWizard.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/applicationGeneralWizard.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/KendoGridDemoController.js"></script>

        <script src="scripts/ngLogger.js"></script>
        <script  src="bower_components/angular-wizard/dist/angular-wizard.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-wizard/dist/angular-wizard.css">
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong, and what is the right 'Angular-Kendo' way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your did good, the only thing i can think of is the use of `new kendo.data.DataSource({})`, you don't need to create a new instance since you're already using the Kendo ui directive that creates it for you (although using this code as is also works), another thing is the fact that we sometimes forget properly adding the third-party library to angular.

```
function ctrl($scope){
         $scope.dataSource = {
            data: [
                { id: 1, name: 'Tennis Balls', department: 'Sports', lastShipment: '10/01/2013' },
                { id: 2, name: 'Basket Balls', department: 'Sports', lastShipment: '10/02/2013' },
                { id: 3, name: 'Oil', department: 'Auto', lastShipment: '10/01/2013' },
                { id: 4, name: 'Filters', department: 'Auto', lastShipment: '10/01/2013' },
                { id: 5, name: 'Dresser', department: 'Home Furnishings', lastShipment: '10/01/2013' }

            ],
             columns:
                 [
                     { "field": "name", "title": "Name"},
                     { "field": "department", "title": "Department"},
                     { "field": "lastShipment", "title": "Last Shipment" }
                 ]
         };
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/Ysxa6/2/

Comment: Thanks! This helped. I notice, that there is a misalignment between column headers and the actual columns. Is there a setting to fix that?

Comment: that's strange, seems like some jsfiddle bug, I'll check it

Comment: changed the html to <div kendo-grid="" k-data-source="dataSource"></div> no more misalignment between column headers. 
http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/Ysxa6/2/